# No resource with given URL found Electron && React

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-router-dom

Hi i have a problem with Electron && React with react router when i create a new windows with the path of component this not charge and send a error No resource with given URL found`

[`image of error`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgTId.png)
[`image of electron.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8YT.png)
[`image of App.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaxVE.png)
[`image of Main.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7b5e.png)

i try in Dev mode and in production mode`

electron.js: new windows function

```
function impresoraConfigWindows(){
  impresoraConfigWin = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    },
    width:500,
    height:430,
    resizable:false,
    autoHideMenuBar:true,
    alwaysOnTop:true,
    title: 'imprimir'
});
impresoraConfigWin.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html#impresoras')}`);
impresoraConfigWin.on('closed', ()=>{
    impresoraConfigWin = null;
});
}
```

App.js:

```
<HashRouter basename='/'>
    <Main cuentas={cuentas} printers={printers} impresoras={impresoras} logged={logged} setLogged={setLogged} cambio={cambio} setCambio={setCambio} planillas={planillas} gastos={gastos} cajas={cajas} targetas={targetas} fecha={fecha} setFecha={setFecha} sesion={sesion} facturas={facturas} categorias={categorias} setSesion={setSesion} socket={socket} mesas={mesas} ingredientes={ingredientes}  productos={productos} tickets={tickets}/>
</HashRouter>
```

Main.js:

```
<Routes>
        <Route path='/'  element={<Login cuentas={cuentas} logged={logged} setLogged={setLogged} fecha={fecha} setFecha={setFecha} socket={socket} sesion={sesion} setSesion={setSesion}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu' element={<AdminMenu/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/cuentas' element={<CuentasMenu/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/cuentas/crear' element={<CrearCuenta socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/cuentas/list' element={<CrearCuenta socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/productos/crear' element={<AddProd ingredientes={ingredientes} categorias={categorias} socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/productos/list' element={<ListaProductos categorias={categorias} productos={productos} ingredientes={ingredientes} socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/ingredientes/crear' element={<AddIng socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/ingredientes/list' element={<AddIng socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/categorias/crear' element={<AddCat socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/categorias/list' element={<AddIng socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/mesas/crear' element={<AddMesa socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin-menu/mesas/list' element={<AddIng socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/planilla-diaria' element={<PlanillaDiaria planillas={planillas} cambios={cambios} setCambios={setCambios} cambio={cambio} setCambio={setCambio} gastos={gastos} fecha={fecha} cajas={cajas} socket={socket}/>}/>
        <Route path='/planilla-diaria/mozo/:idcuenta' element={<CerrarMozo socket={socket} cajas={cajas} targetas={targetas} fecha={fecha} mesas={mesas} cuentas={cuentas} productos={productos} ingredientes={ingredientes}  facturas={facturas}/>}/>
        <Route path='/planilla-diaria/mozos' element={<Mozo fecha={fecha} cuentas={cuentas}/>}/>
        <Route path='/impresoras' element={<Impresoras socket={socket} impresoras={impresoras}/>}/>
        <Route path='/historial-mesas/mozos' element={<MozosList fecha={fecha} cuentas={cuentas}/>}/>
        <Route path='/historial-mesas/:idcuenta' element={<VerMesas mesas={mesas} fecha={fecha} facturas={facturas} tickets={tickets} productos={productos} cuentas={cuentas} ingredientes={ingredientes} />}/>
        <Route path='/mesas/' element={<MesasList tickets={tickets} logged={logged} mesas={mesas} setSesion={setSesion} socket={socket} sesion={sesion}/>}/>
        <Route path='/mesas/:idmesa/:idcuenta' element={<MesasPage fecha={fecha} cuentas={cuentas} categorias={categorias} mesas={mesas} ingredientes={ingredientes} socket={socket} sesion={sesion} productos={productos} tickets={tickets}/>}/>
     </Routes>
```

Comment: please writ the code don't use images

Comment: sorry jeje i change this rigth now